# RequestFailedException/403 Forbidden errors accessing Azure Key Vault with role based access policies

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I have a scenario where I'm getting the below exception when trying to debug an ASP.NET Core Web Application in Visual Studio that has connected services for Azure Key Vault and Azure Application Configuration resources connected to an App Service.  The user that I'm signed into Visual Studio with appears to have the correct permissions on the KV and the same as another developer who does NOT get the error I do.  I can also successfully view and inspect the values for all secrets in the Secrets page for the AKV while signed into Azure using the same user.

The error:

> C:\Professional\Projects\Inventive\inventivegroup\mgr360>dotnet watch run
> watch : Started
> Unhandled exception. Azure.RequestFailedException: Service request failed.
> Status: 403 (Forbidden)
>
> Content:
> {"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"Caller is not authorized to perform action on resource.\r\nIf role assignments, deny assignments or role definitions were changed recently, please observe propagation time.\r\nCaller: appid=c41ed4ac-ID-SNIP;oid=3108ce41-ID-SNIP;iss=https://sts.windows.net/359ccce3-ID-SNIP/\r\nAction: 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets/readMetadata/action'\r\nResource: '/subscriptions/666a80a4-ID-SNIP/resourcegroups/RESOURCEGROUPNAME/providers/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/webappvaultname'\r\nAssignment: (not found)\r\nVault: NameOfWebAppvault;location=eastus\r\n","innererror":{"code":"ForbiddenByRbac"}}}
>
> Headers:
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> Pragma: no-cache
> x-ms-keyvault-region: eastus
> x-ms-client-request-id: bd5ef0e5-ID-SNIP
> x-ms-request-id: 8053b6d8-ID-SNIP
> x-ms-keyvault-service-version: 1.2.236.0
> x-ms-keyvault-network-info: conn_type=Ipv4;addr=50.IP.SNIP;act_addr_fam=InterNetwork;
> x-ms-keyvault-rbac-cache: ra_age=0;da_age=7453;rd_age=7453;brd_age=11547;ra_notif_age=99;dec_lev=3;
> X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
> Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains
> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
> Date: Fri, 23 Apr 2021 18:21:57 GMT
> Content-Length: 701
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
> Expires: -1
>
> at Azure.Security.KeyVault.KeyVaultPipeline.SendRequestAsync(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Azure.Security.KeyVault.KeyVaultPipeline.GetPageAsync[T](Uri firstPageUri, String nextLink, Func`1 itemFactory, String operationName, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Azure.Core.PageResponseEnumerator.FuncAsyncPageable`1.AsPages(String continuationToken, Nullable`1 pageSizeHint)+MoveNext() at Azure.Core.PageResponseEnumerator.FuncAsyncPageable`1.AsPages(String continuationToken, Nullable`1 pageSizeHint)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult() at Azure.AsyncPageable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext()
> at Azure.AsyncPageable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)+MoveNext() at Azure.AsyncPageable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
> at Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.LoadAsync()
> at Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.LoadAsync()
> at Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.Load()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
> at FOO_Web_App.Program.<>c.b__1_2(WebHostBuilderContext hostingContext, IConfigurationBuilder config) in C:\Professional\Projects\FOO\Program.cs:line 37
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IConfigurationBuilder builder)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
> at FOO_Web_App.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Professional\Projects\FOO\Program.cs:line 17
>
> watch : Exited with error code -532462766

The code (which also occurs running 'dotnet watch run'):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VaultUri"));
                config.AddAzureKeyVault(
                    keyVaultEndpoint,
                    new DefaultAzureCredential());
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    //Error here at config.Build():
                    //Azure.RequestFailedException: 'Service request failed.
                    //Status: 403(Forbidden)
                    //Content:
                    //{"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"Caller is not authorized to perform action on resource.\r\nIf role assignments, deny assignments or role definitions were changed recently, please observe propagation time.\r\nCaller: appid=c41ed4ac-ID-SNIP;oid=3108ce41-ID-SNIP;iss=https://sts.windows.net/359ccce3-ID-SNIP/\r\nAction: 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets/readMetadata/action'\r\nResource: '/subscriptions/666a80a4-ID-SNIP/resourcegroups/RESOURCEGROUPNAME/providers/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/webappvaultname'\r\nAssignment: (not found)\r\nVault: NameOfWebAppvault;location=eastus\r\n","innererror":{"code":"ForbiddenByRbac"}}}
                    var settings = config.Build();
                    config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
                    {
                        options.Connect(settings["ConnectionStrings:AppConfig"])
                            .ConfigureKeyVault(kv => { kv.SetCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential()); });
                    });
                }).UseStartup<Startup>());
}
```

I verified my logged in user through PowerShell to ensure it is correct:

[image: Powershell script results]

And these are the role assignments in Access Control:

[image: Role assignments in Azure KV]

I know the error references "observe propagation time", but it's been hours and the same error occurred yesterday.  Is this a tenant issue?  Azure KV or RBAC configuration issue?  Code issue?  Dev environment/user account issue?

Comment: What about your access policies on the vault - has your app and/or user been granted the correct vault level permissions?

Comment: Check the access policies on the azure key vault, you dont have permission on your id thats why you are getting this error. 

Comment: The Access Policies page is not used when Azure role-based access control is enabled!

Answer (score 7):

Being an Owner or contributor does not give you access to read keys from the key vault.

Being owner does give you the right to grant yourself access to read the keys.

If you give yourself the key vault administrator role you will be able to read the keys.

> Key Vault Contributor role is for management plane operations to
> manage key vaults. It does not allow access to keys, secrets and
> certificates.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-guide?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: But I AM a Key Vault Admin - see "Eric" listed in the KVA section

Comment: You are owner, you need to grant yourself the right to get and list keys

Comment: I'm already a member of the Key Vault Administrator role - doesn't that inherently have the right to get and list keys??

Comment: That does not show up on the screen dump. If you have recently been given the role, try loging out and in again, so that your group membership is updated.

Comment: The screen dump of the "Access control (IAM)" page shows my name ("Eric Legault" - partially blurred) right between the two red arrows in the list of Key Vault Administrators. Am I missing something obvious??

Comment: This saved me SO much time. Turns our I was owner but not Key Vault Secret User. That fixed it for me. That and setting the tenant ID on the credential options to match the directory ID of the key vault, but that's another error that I got.

Comment: Like Eric, I was key vault admin, but still got unauthorized error. Issue for me was "Public network access is disabled and request is not from a trusted service nor via an approved private link". Hence managing from Azure portal errored. Changed key vault to semi-public whitelisted IP, try again, now works.